# Query entry with distinct source?

Tags: xml, linq

I'm building an RSS reader where only the most recent post from a variety of authors will load, meaning, each source blog only has one post. The following piece of code produces a row of buttons in a list box each one having the name of the blog and the publishing date of the post as text, and a link to the blog when clicked. There are too many buttons because it makes one for each publishing.

I would like to know how to create the IEnumerable blogPosts with only object Blogs where BlogName is distinct. I don't know if it should be a more refined Linq query (I've been trying this in many variations to no avail) or a loop through blogPosts to somehow nullify all those Blogs with dups as BlogNames.

```
            private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,
          DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          if (e.Error == null)
          {
            //declare the document xml to parse
            XDocument LABlogs = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            //declare the namespace of the xml to parse
            XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

                //set the variable to collect the content for the buttons in the blogList ListBox
                //I'm parsing two nodes on the same level, then thier descendants both element and attribute
                var blogPosts = from source in LABlogs.Descendants(xmlns + "source")
                                from entry in LABlogs.Descendants(xmlns + "entry")

                                //someplace here I want to filter to where the source is distinct
                                select new Blog

                                { 
                                    //parsing the feed to get the button properties
                                    BlogName =(string)source.Element(xmlns + "title").Value,
                                    BlogUrl = (string)source.Element(xmlns + "link").Attribute("href").Value,
                                    BlogPub = (string)entry.Element(xmlns + "published").Value
                                };

                //add the var containing the button properties to the ListBox
                this.blogListBox.ItemsSource = blogPosts;

          }
        }
}
         public class Blog
          {
            public string BlogName { get; set; }
            public string BlogUrl { get; set; }
            public string BlogPub { get; set; }
          }
```

Comment: What do you get now?  Nobody is going to spend time to debug your program for you.  You have to ask a specific question.

Comment: This much works to load a row of buttons in the listbox with the BlogName and BlogPub (published date) as text on the button and the BlogUrl links out. Currently it loads one button for every published post, but what I need is one button per blog. I don't know how to implement Distinct for BlogName( or where to implement it) to affect the entire blogPost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Distinct Linq method, passing a IEqualityComparer:

```
    private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            //declare the document xml to parse
            XDocument LABlogs = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            //declare the namespace of the xml to parse
            XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

            //set the variable to collect the content for the buttons in the blogList ListBox
            //I'm parsing two nodes on the same level, then thier descendants both element and attribute
            var blogPosts = from source in LABlogs.Descendants(xmlns + "source")
                            from entry in LABlogs.Descendants(xmlns + "entry")
                            //someplace here I want to filter to where the source is distinct
                            select new Blog
                            {
                                //parsing the feed to get the button properties
                                BlogName = (string)source.Element(xmlns + "title").Value,
                                BlogUrl = (string)source.Element(xmlns + "link").Attribute("href").Value,
                                BlogPub = (string)entry.Element(xmlns + "published").Value
                            };

            // ******************************** //
            // >>>> here is the Distinct code <<<<
            // ******************************** //
            blogPosts.Distinct(new BlogNameComparer());

            //add the var containing the button properties to the ListBox
            this.blogListBox.ItemsSource = blogPosts;
        }
    }
```

Code of the equality comparer:

```
public class BlogNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Blog>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<Blog>.Equals(Blog x, Blog y)
    {
        if (x == null) return y == null;
        if (y == null) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.BlogName, y.BlogName);
    }
    int IEqualityComparer<Blog>.GetHashCode(Blog obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.BlogName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: xxxooo! That works like a charm. The one thing was that I needed to add the distinct blogPosts to the list box like so `this.blogListBox.ItemsSource = blogPosts.Distinct(new BlogNameComparer());`  This is a very useful thing for me to know; thanks again.